# change the main hader in testcafe-reports-html

Tags: testing, automated-tests, report, e2e-testing, testcafe

how i can change the text in header of reports?
form "TestCafe Test Summary" to custom header

```
 <h1 class="text-primary">TestCafe Test Summary</h1>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this text is hardcoded in the source code of the testcafe-reporter-html plugin: https://github.com/picuscreative/testcafe-reporter-html/blob/1e2868a3303c2e4f26951ea9c1f0b724be7d5a10/src/index.js.

You can create a pull request with some changes that will make this text configurable.